10th Anniversary of Joomla SE!
In April Joomla SE turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

I was here since the beginning, and was really happy when Joomla's Stack Exchange was approved (as I recall, it was the second attempt).
I really have benefited from the contributions of everyone here.
Here everything is more organized, and the contributors seem more knowledgeable compared to other sources, especially for development/programming.
Keep it up!
